# Cycle through results using "next-error" & "previous-error"

Tags: emacs, elisp

I use both "next-error" & "previous-error" to cycle through results. But once reaching the last entry the cycle doesn't go back to the top and so on.

Is there a way to have the cycling continue to the top once reaching the bottom and vice versa?

Comment: If the function involved is something like `compilation-next-error` which is used in conjunction with `next-error` when looking at a `*Compile-Log*`, then perhaps you could modify the former by adding after `... "Moved past last %s") (point-max)` something like `(goto-char (point-min)) (next-error)` -- and a `defalias` to your new function `ammari-compilation-next-error` after `(require 'compile)`.  This is completely *untested*, but seems like a plausible answer.  The same thing for `"Moved back before first %s" (point-min)` . . . only add `(goto-char (point-max)) (previous-error)`.

Comment: Also note that `next-error` takes a second optional argument `RESET` to restart from the beginning. Your own function could check what next-error did and then just call it again: `(next-error 1 t)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote some elisp to achieve this, here it

```
(defvar my-modeline-flash-color "#af00d7")

(defun my-indicate-error-nav-wrapped (direction)
  "Display a message in minibuffer indicating that we wrapped
also flash the mode-line"
  (let ((mode-line-color (face-background 'mode-line)))
    (message "Wrapped %s error" (symbol-name direction))
    (set-face-background 'mode-line my-modeline-flash-color)
    (sit-for 0.3)
    (set-face-background 'mode-line mode-line-color)))

(defun my-next-error-wrapped (&optional arg reset)
  "Jumps to previous error if at first error jump to last error instead.
Prefix argument ARG says how many error messages to move forwards (or
backwards, if negative). With just C-u as prefix moves to first error"
  (interactive "P")
  (condition-case nil
      (call-interactively 'next-error)
    ('user-error (progn (next-error 1 t)
                        (my-indicate-error-nav-wrapped 'next)))))

(defun my-jump-to-last-error (buffer)
  "Jump to last error in the BUFFER, this assumes that
the error is at last but third line"
  (save-selected-window
    (select-window (get-buffer-window buffer))
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (forward-line -3)
    (call-interactively 'compile-goto-error)))

(defun my-previous-error-wrapped (&optional arg)
  "Jumps to previous error if at first error jump to last error instead.
Prefix argument ARG says how many error messages to move backwards (or
forwards, if negative)."
  (interactive "P")
  (condition-case nil
      (if (compilation-buffer-p (current-buffer))
          (compilation-previous-error 1)
        (call-interactively 'previous-error))
    ('user-error (progn
                   (let ((error-buffer (next-error-find-buffer)))
                     ;; If the buffer has an associated error buffer use it to
                     ;; to move to last error
                     (if (and (not (eq (current-buffer) error-buffer))
                              (compilation-buffer-p error-buffer))
                         (my-jump-to-last-error error-buffer)
                       ;; Otherwise move to last point and invoke previous error
                       (goto-char (point-max))
                       (call-interactively 'previous-error))
                     (my-indicate-error-nav-wrapped 'previous))))))
```

Bind the functions `my-previous-error-wrapped` and `my-next-error-wrapped` to some convenient keys and you are good to go. The modeline will be flashed momentarily using the `my-modeline-flash-color`, a minibuffer message will also be displayed when wrapping.

**How does this work?**

Just in case you want to how this works here is the explanation, `next-error` internally uses the value of `next-error-function` to find the function to call to get the next error in the buffer, now *most* of these functions (or at least the ones I checked) try to navigate to next error in the buffer, or signal an `user-error` if there are no more errors in the buffer. In the above function we are calling `next-error` and handling `user-error`. Now if `user-error` occurs we make a second call to `next-error` with the argument `reset` as `t`, which takes us to the first error in the buffer. You read more about arguments passed `next-error` using `C-h f next-error RET`. Read [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Errors.html) to learn more about elisp errors. Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks Iqbal, I will test this today. Did you have anything comparable for previous-error that could wrap as well.
Also, It would be nice to have an indication before the wrapping when you reach the end of list, just so the user would know he wrapped. Is there a way to trigger mode-line flash, same way when you reach end of list using next-error functionality.

Comment: Excellent work Iqbal. The flashing works great. However, my-previous-error-wrapped is not working as supposed to.  It still simulates the generic previous-error behavior, no wrapping and no flashing.

Comment: I might have found out the problem. In my compilation window, after all the results I have a blank line then a line that mentions the time the search finished and if "successful" then another blank line. So, I believe your line (goto-char (point-max)) is not really matching to the last point of the buffer. Is there a way to "goto-char (point-max - 3)" so I can offset the irrelevant lines?

Comment: @Ammari, Actually the previous code used to work only for 'flycheck-errors', this modified version should work with 'grep errors' also. Admittedly this turned out to be too hacky but it works™ (at least as far as I have tested). Let me know this works for you

Comment: Works beautifully! Much appreciated Iqbal.

Answer (score 5):

A simple solution is to hit `C-u` and calling next-error to start over.

---

I previously tried the following but it's obviously not working, we can not always set the REVERT argument…

```
(defun my-nexterrorloop ()
     (interactive)
     (next-error 1 t))
```

I checked the documentation of the function with `C-h a next-error RET` and I read:
«

```
(next-error &optional ARG RESET)
The RESET argument specifies that we should restart from the beginning.
```

»

Comment: Then you always need to call that function manually as soon as you reach the last error?

Comment: No, you should bind it to a keybinding, for example you can overwrite the predifined `C-x backquote` that normally calls `next-error`: (global-set-key (kbd "C-x `") 'my-nexterrorloop).

Comment: Yes, but you always pass in `t` for the `RESET` argument, which will make the function always start from the beginning and never advance. Try it yourself.

Comment: What ? I totally tried it myself. Double checking. OMG you're right. So sorry :S trying sth else.

Comment: A simple solution is to hit `C-u` and calling next-error to start over.

Answer (score 2):

I arranged my next error f2 key in this simple way:

```
(global-set-key [f2]
  '(lambda () (interactive) 
      (condition-case nil (next-error) 
         (error (next-error 1 t)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

**An alternative:**

Use [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles) key C-` (Control backquote) in the compilation buffer (e.g. `*grep*`).  It shows you all of the compilation errors (e.g. `grep` hits) as *completion* candidates.  This is a [special case](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Other_Search_Commands#toc8) of [**Icicles** search](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview).

- You can cycle among the corresponding source-code locations using `C-down`.  And that wraps around (which is your request).  `C-up` cycles backward (up), and it also wraps around.
- You can type some text in the minibuffer to temporarily narrow the set of hits (errors) to those that match your input, and then cycle among them.  Change your minibuffer input to match a different subset of hits.
- You do not need to access source locations in order.  You can access any of them individually, using `C-mouse-2` -- or by cycling to it using `down` or `up` without Control, and hitting `RET` to choose it.  Cycling without Control pressed cycles the current completion candidate. cycling with Control pressed opens each corresponding source location as you cycle among candidates.
- You can even [replace](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Other_Search_Commands#toc9) text that appears in search hits (errors).